# TWLauncher crashes on App installation

Tags: android, launcher

Faced this problem, and after spending hours of time on this, got the solution.

The issue is, whenever I installed the app, the TWLauncher of the Samsung device, enters a crash loop, where it always crashes.

Answer (score 0):

No idea why, but when I replaced the icon with an other one, it fixed the issue. So use a different image and try, and it will work! Just thought I would share this with all of you.